# fails to connect github with ssh while building python dockerfile

Tags: python, git, docker, ssh

### What I want to do

I'm trying to connect to github with ssh while building python docker image.

```
FROM python:3.10.4 AS builder

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /running

COPY ./pyproject.toml ./

# copy key
COPY github.pem /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Add the necessary SSH config
RUN echo 'Host * \n\
  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa \n\
' > /root/.ssh/config

RUN which ssh

RUN ssh -T git@github.com
```

### instead below happened

the result is...

```
#12 [8/8] RUN ssh -T git@github.com
#12 sha256:009cd770ecaf452b09b48969487c7957d5c5fddf449cc2ea54bc195b09c44e37
#12 1.230 Host key verification failed.
#12 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ssh -T git@github.com]: exit code: 255
```

but I can connect to github well with that ssh key in my local mac

### the question

how do I connect to github while building docker image?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: The problem is with the **host** key, not **user** key. Update known hosts: `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`